# How does Xarray coordinates and plot() for downsampled data?

Tags: python, python-xarray

I understand that if the data and data coordinates are of same size, we can just use .plot() to get the plots with all metadata. But, lets say I pass a parameter with ds.isel(low_resolution) that gives me a downsampled data. Is there a way to downsample the coordinates as well based on this downsampled data? For example, my original xarray is of size (360,720) and works well with the plot(), but now that I use ds.isel(low_resolution), I get the downsampled data of size (90,180). But the coordinates are still the same of shape(360,720) because I had been using lazyloading in the backend. Plot() doesnt work on this case and gives dimension mismatch error. Looking for any inputs!

Comment: If this is really the case it sounds like a bug. If you can provide a minimal reproducible example we might be able to help.